# Cordova iOS Webview and native swift 3 Communication

Tags: ios, cordova, swift3, webview

I have my application ready in Cordova. But I need to convert it in native ios for better animation effects and native mapbox SDK. 
I have used cordova ios webview to display current cordova app and have added some native buttons.

On click of native buttons I want to trigger functionalities from cordova app and in some cases I need to trigger native viewcontrollers to display map.

Can someone help me to establish this communication?

This is my viewcontroller which display's cordova code :

```
import UIKit
import Cordova
import NVActivityIndicatorView

class WebViewController: CDVViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.isOpaque = false
        self.wwwFolderName = "/www";
        self.startPage = "events.html"

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        self.view.frame = rect;

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue? I am also facing same issue :(

Comment: Hi? Did you fix this? It's not good just asking and not helping